# Variables did not replaced

Tags: java, docx, docx4j

I wrote some code to replace variables in docx tamplate file header.

```
List<SectionWrapper> sectionWrappers = this.wordMLPackage.getDocumentModel().getSections();
for (SectionWrapper sw : sectionWrappers) {
    HeaderFooterPolicy hfp = sw.getHeaderFooterPolicy();
    HeaderPart defaultHP = hfp.getDefaultHeader();
        if (defaultHP != null) {
            defaultHP.variableReplace(getVariablesForChange());
            if (hfp.getFirstHeader() != null) {
              hfp.getFirstHeader().variableReplace(getVariablesForChange());
            }
        }
}
```

`getVariablesForChange()` is a Map has contains the variables and values.
When I running the unit test the replace is corectly fine but I use this in my web application on Tomee Plume the variables does not replaced. 
For example the variable is: `${TOCHANGE}` it looks like this after change TOCHANGE.

Docx4j version is: 3.3.6

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't work if your KEY is split across separate runs in your docx.

See https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/docx4j/model/datastorage/migration/VariablePrepare.java

Comment: Would you please give me more information about that? I don't see why working the same process in Unit test. What should I do to work that on Tomee plume?

Comment: post the document.xml content into the question, or the entire docx file somewhere so i can see it

Comment: You can download here: header1.xml: https://a.uguu.se/j6jMKl78riVG_header1.xml  and
document.xml : https://a.uguu.se/31sz6FU0jNYS_document.xml